# Jquery ajax php validation and keypress 'enter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation

I code a multistep form with jquery ajax and php validation. 
It'working.
Today, for last verification, I made a wrong move pressing enter key. 
I was on first step and all **my work have gone with the Wind**.

If I prevent the submit button with the present code, impossible to submit my form at the end.
is it possible to stop action with enterkey : my validation is code on click function.
Thanks.

```
 $("#myForm").submit(function(e){
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: Try `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Thanks to answer. Just try but it"s bloking the true submit and the end of form even by click function

Comment: disable by default submit button attribute html "disabled=disabled"

Comment: no, no working with submit disable on html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you give all your inputs in your form a class of `inputs` then:

```
 $('.inputs').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        console.log('enter pressed');
        return false;
    }

});
```